# How To Set Position as a Variable (Corona SDK)

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk

So I am making a game like pong in Corona and I am stuck at how to get the paddles to trace the ball. I have defined the ball's x coordinate as `ball.x = ballx` and `ballx = 160` but when I use

```
local myListener = function( event )
   upperpad.x = ballx
   lowerpad.x = ballx
end

Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", myListener )
```

to keep the paddles x value updated to the ball's x value, it stays constant. How can I express `ballx` as a changing value and get the paddles to mirror the ball's x value?

Comment: Add  ballx = ball.x in the function `myListener` will change the ballx.

Comment: You should accept my answer in your other question. And for this question, I think sometimes you need to show more information (code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ballx value stays constant because you're probably not updating it, and changing directly ball.x instead. Indeed, this is the way to do it: you should use ball.x as this is is the real value that's being changed, and not ballx.

Yet, if you still want to use a reference value to ball.x, you can set `ballx = ball.x` and **then** update the **ballx** value directly.

When you're done updating the ballx value, you can update the ball.x value as well, and the paddles just like you did.

```
local updateBall = function()

    ballx = ballx + 20 --update the ballx value

end

Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", updateBall)

local myListener = function(event)

   ball.x = ballx --then update the ball itself with the ballx value

   upperpad.x = ballx --and make the paddles follow
   lowerpad.x = ballx

end

Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", myListener)
```

EDIT: If you want to manually set the paddles' position depending on the ball's (which is handled by the physics engine), simply make them follow the original ball.x value. You **don't** need ballx.

```
local movePaddles = function(event)

   upperpad.x = ball.x
   lowerpad.x = ball.x

end

Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", movePaddles)
```

Comment: That bit of code would work great if I was manually updating the ball'x x value, however it is already moving on its own through a physics engine. Basically I set 4 bounds around the screen and right now the ball just bounces around, my goal is to have the paddles follow the balls movement and have it only bounce off of the paddle. Is there any way to track the x position in a physics environment?

Comment: Thank you so much! Exactly what I needed! (: